# How to save some content into a column and read it back to an object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have string array. I need this string array to be saved as a comma separated single string inside a single text column. But when i read and write the  hibernate entity i will just set and get the `List<String>`. I want to know a sample and how can I do it with hibernate annotations.

Comment: what have u tried till now ?

Comment: i know there is an annotation which can specify a class to transform data. Which i used 2 years ago. But i cant remember how and what it is. PS: I dont want to write it inside all getters and setters. I want some nicer solution which i know its avaiable out there

Comment: Do you mean hibernate usertypes?

Comment: Thank you @mreiterer, You can submit it as the answer. I'll accept it

Comment: For the person who downvoted ? Can i have some feedback ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate UserTypes.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html